# How to immediately get value from observer?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have observer, which stores styles for some `DOM` elements tree.

Also, I have many inputs, in which i can change this styles.

```
<input
    type="text"
    [value]="elementData.getSpecificStyle('elementClassName', 'background')"
    (keyup)="elementData.setSpecificStyle('elementClassName', 'background', $event.target.value)"
>
```

### StylesService

```
public setStyle (clazz: string, styleName: string, styleValue: string): void {
    if (!this._styles[clazz]) {
        this._styles[clazz] = {};
    }

    this._styles[clazz][styleName] = styleValue;

    this.stylesSubject.next(this._styles);
}

private getSpecificStyle (clazz: string, styleName: string): string {
    let result: string = '';

    this.styles.subscribe((styles: Observable<Object>) => {
        result = styles[clazz][styleName];
    });

    return result;
}
```

All styles inside observer, so, when I want to put some of style value as input value - I need to subscribe on observer like in `getSpecificStyle` method.

That normal, when I can get styles asynchronously, but in that situation I just want to get current value from observer immediately.

This code works fine, but i want to know, there any way to replace that code

```
let result: string = '';

this.styles.subscribe((styles: Observable<Object>) => {
   result = styles[clazz][styleName];
});

return result;
```

on something more simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible when `styles` is an observable. Observables work that way by design. They push a value when one is available. 
If you don't want to use `subscribe` you need to change `styles` to not return an observable.

Comment: It sadly, that there is no any default syntax sugar in rxjs for that case =(